# pyinstaller: Cannot compile my code into .exe

Tags: python, compiler-errors, compilation, pyinstaller, openmdao

I am writing this post to ask you some help about how to properly use pyinstaller. Actually, I built a little program which is using the module openmdao (a framework of optimizing algorithms) which I am currently trying to compile into an .exe file.

I have not noticed any troubles during the compilation, but I am trying to run the .exe file, it seems that the program cannot import the openmdao module and I get this error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI255402\\openmdao\\utils\\unit_library.ini'
[688] Failed to execute script '__main__' due to unhandled exception!
```

Nevertheless, the module opendmao was already in my python virtual environment I mean before my compilation attempt). I do not know if I need to add a path or something else in the .spec file, to specify that openmdao needs to be imported.

Has anyone already seen a such situation?
Many thanks in advance for your help

Edit: to run the compilation, I used `pyinstaller one_file.spec`
and here is my .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['__main__.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(r"C:\...\files_to_use", "...//files_to_use"),
],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='MyProject',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True, icon='my_project.ico')
```

Comment: what command line arguments are you using for pyinstaller/what options in spec file?

Comment: I've just edited my question; this should answer to your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem by:

1. Package your script into a directory (do not use `-F`, as pyinstaller will default to `-D`).
2. Copy the `<openmdao package path>/utils/unit_library.ini` file to `dist/<your dirname>/openmdao/utils/unit_library.ini`.

This issue might be fixed by adding a hook file to openmdao, but I am not familiar with pyinstaller hooks yet. Nevertheless, the method above should work.

Note: Please replace `<openmdao package path>` and `<your dirname>` with the actual path and directory name.